# Apache2 can't start: ssl.load Permission Denied

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

I'm setting up an HTTPS server on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server.

After configuring everything, when I try to start the server I get:

```
root@dns2:/etc/apache2# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load: Permission denied
   ...fail!
```

The relevant line 204 in apache2.conf is `Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load`

mods-enabled (soft-links to mods-available as per standard):

```
root@dns2:/etc/apache2# ls -l mods-enabled
total 0
<stuff>
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2011-06-17 16:24 ssl.conf -> ../mods-available/ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2011-06-17 16:24 ssl.load -> ../mods-available/ssl.load
<stuff>
```

mods-available:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2412 2010-11-18 13:18 ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 2010-11-18 13:18 ssl.load
```

I can't see any reason why this error comes up.  I am utterly confounded.  Any ideas?

EDIT: sites-available and sites-enabled directory permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-06-17 16:36 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-06-17 16:28 sites-enabled
```

EDIT2: I tried disabling the ssl module and starting apache:

```
root@dns2:/etc/apache2# a2dismod ssl
Module ssl disabled.
Run '/etc/init.d/apache2 restart' to activate new configuration!
root@dns2:/etc/apache2# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 236 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl: Permission denied
   ...fail!
```

000-default-ssl points to the default ssl virtual host config file.  Again, all permissions are right.  After removing 000-default-ssl, apache starts normally.  Obviously, since now it's back to the default configuration...

Comment: What are the permisisons on the `mods-enabled` and the `mods-available` directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's happening.  My AppArmor profile for apache2 was blocking access to mod_ssl.  Allowing apache2 to access said files in its AppArmor profile fixes everything.  Well, at least I know AppArmor is doing its job properly =)

I don't know if I should ask another question for this, but is AppArmor good enough security for apache?  I really don't want to chroot apache, and I've heard something about chrooting not being very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check not only the directory the files are in but all paths up until that directory. No point checking /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ when (eg) /etc/apache2/ is only 700 ;)

try starting it as root using apaches control command.

`apache2ctl start`

or

`sudo apache2ctl start`

as a user. Check if you get the same error or any more information.

Comment: /etc and /etc/apache2 are both 755.  `apache2ctl start` gives the same error.  Thanks for the reminder though; I'm sure I'm missing something ridiculously simple somewhere...

Comment: I would disable ssl, start apache and confirm it starts ok, then enable it again using /usr/sbin/a2enmod incase you did it any other way. There must be some hidden error like /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so is the one that's the permission issue or error.

Comment: What user is apache running as, to be sure check with `grep ^User /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and/or `grep APACHE_RUN /etc/apache2/envvars`. I'm sure if this was www-data then you should be able to su to it and cat the files in question just for curiosity.

Comment: I checked apache2.conf and envvars, apache is indeed running as www-data. `su www-data` and I can cat both ssl.load and 000-default-ssl fine, as expected.  Tried starting apache again, same error.